# SOAP error when executing onvif server

Tags: soap, onvif

I get the following error when I try to run my onvifserver , everything is fine and It was running correctly before, but now suddenly I get this error:

```
SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender [no subcode]
"End of file or no input: Network is unreachable"
Detail: [no detail]
```

I was trying to see why and apparently, it's when I call soap_wsdd_listen that He does send that error, the call to soap_wsdd_Hello is OK

Can you tell me please what can I do to solve that ? thank you;